# Is there any way to pause/continue the progress in LoadingBar.js

Tags: javascript, frontend, progress-bar, loading, loadingbar.js

I have the following code. Its just create a bar and start loading upto 100%. How to pause/continue the loading?

```
    var bar1 = new ldBar("#bar1", {});
    bar1.set(100);
```

Is there any function or any way to continue/pause the loading?

[Loading.js link](https://loading.io/progress/)

Your help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What happens when you set it to 60, wait a minute and set it to 100?

Comment: from what I can see in the docs, this library does not make the loading by itself, just keeps track on another element's attribute (in this case data-value). If you don't have control over that process (whatever that "loading" is) then I do not see how could you do that.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your valuable answers. I have moved on to another library @RudyMartin, jabaa

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you need that pause/continue feature on clicking a button.

There's one way by using the **setInterval** method. You can create a variable(assume it is x) and set its value to 0. And using setInterval method, increment the value of x. Pass the same value of x as **data-value** attribute.
After button click you can trigger **clearInterval** method to pause the progress and use same process to continue the progress